# How to include external js file in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I tried all the ways in the master file and in the aspx file, and in the cs file, but it never works the following are the ways i tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/example3.js")%>'></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="example3.js">


protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

        if (scriptManager == null) return;

        scriptManager.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference { Path = "~/Scripts/example3.js" });
        scriptManager.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference { Path = "~/Scripts/jit.js" });
    }
```

Comment: If your javascript files are located in a Scripts folder then `<script src="/Scripts/example3.js"></script>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ResolveClientUrl` instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/example3.js")%>'></script>
```

If you still can't see it, check the page source after run (in IE, from Alt --> View --> Source), search for "example.js" and check how the path was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i managed to solve my problem. the problem was not in how to reference it, but i was not calling the function in the js file, that's why the js file was not working